Cannot reconnect to temporary queue on Azure service bus
I have a simple service that uses MassTransit. During development, I don't want to create permanent queues/topics, especially on the Azure service bus, to which I don't have admin access. So, I used this method to create temporary queues. I also configured an endpoint name prefix.
After I configured my application to connect to the Azure service bus, everything worked fine. The MassTransit debug log shows that all the endpoints are configured as expected. However, if I restart the application, the MassTransit log shows all the endpoints are configured, but messages cannot be received. I can see the SEND log but never got the RECEIVED log. Everything will work again if I change the endpoint name prefix. If I wait for some time, maybe hours or days, and reuse the previous prefix, the application will work again.
But I don't have the above issue if I use RabbitMq as the backend message transport. So, I feel there's something wrong with the Azure service bus, especially with regard to temporary queues. But I am not sure if it has to do with the way MassTransit configures the queues/topics on the service bus or if it has to do with the service bus resource configuration/creation.

What does MT do with ASB topology to achieve the temporary consumer implementation?

IDK. I could not find any ASB document about the Temporary topic. But there's an auto-delete-on-idle feature.

All I could see was temporary endpoints that use in-memory implementation. But even then I don't know if it's applicable to ASB or what MT is doing. Sadly, that documentation is too poor to be used as a proper manual.
